# Copy, paste, move colored squares - but keep them aligned to the grid

Tags: inkscape, svg, grids, alignment

I am developing [a word game for iOS](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/tree/master/Scroll) and would like to use [an SVG file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3ABlank_Scrabble_board_with_coordinates.svg) as the gaming board.

The SVG file (author: Denelson83, Wikimedia Commons) is almost perfect for my game - except for displaced colored squares.

**My question is:**

How could I please copy such a colored square (is it a *Group*?), then paste it and move the new square to a new spot - but still keep it aligned to the grid?

[image: screenshot]

As an Inkscape newbie I have already found out, that I can jump to the "original" with **Shift-D**.

And I can hold **CTRL** key to move objects horizontally or vertically.

But I still don't understand how to keep the moved square aligned to the grid (which also seems to be in a separate layer - so how did the author manage to keep all squares aligned to the grid?)

And also I can't find some view/dialog/toolbar, which would show me the coordinates of the object being dragged by me (I only see the coordinates of the mouse pointer at the bottom right). If I could see/change those coordinates, then I could (in a tiresome way) calculate and set the coordinates for the new squares...

**UPDATE:**

I've toggled **Snap to grid** and also enabled showing the grid:

[image: grid]

but the square doesn't snap to the grid when I drag it.

And also the grid is too small and I can't find how to make its cells broader.

**UPDATE 2:**

I have found where to set the grid size (15 x 15) and offset:

[image: properties]

But while the grid looks ok now and snaps too - it snaps in the wrong places as shown below.

[image: snapping]

Why doesn't the grid snap at the square's borders?

Is this maybe [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/727281) in Inkscape? How to workaround it please?

**UPDATE 3:** I've received an offline advice to hold ALT while dragging a square

Comment: as per the last image, it looks like it snaps the _text_ to the grid?

Comment: Yes, Inkscape also writes smth. about the text baseline... But I need to move the squares.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to snap the whole group, **you need to enable *"Snap bounding box corners"***, by clicking on the proper icon in snap toolbar:

[image: Snap bounding box corners]

Usually this flag isn't enabled and you see the snap to text baseline:

[image: Default snap to text]

Enabling this flag you can see the snap to the bounding box of the group (or the selection);

[image: Snap to bounding box corners]

You can change the behaviour of the snap using the other buttons in the toolbar. See [here](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Snapping.html) for reference.

Be aware that **the snap depends from the position of your mouse in the selection**: if you begin to drag the group with the mouse near the text, the snap would be related to the text, if your mouse is near the top-left corner of the box, the snap would be related to the top-left corner of the box (if "Snap bounding box corner" is enabled), and so on.