# Trying to connect these objects but I can't snap to an element using Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I'm using the freehand tool (F6) in Inkscape but when I enable snapping, it snaps to a grid point. Also, as "cables" will be crossing between them, how can I add some curve at this point to differentiate both paths?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: You say you are using Freehand, but then your question mentions Inkscape. Which is it?  What do you mean by "it snaps to a grid point" - what is it? And when you say "crossing between them" - what do you mean by them?  The image you posted is not helping. Can you show what you are actually trying to achieve, not the individual parts? Perhaps draw what you want with pencil and paper if you can't do it. I'm voting to close this question as it's totally unclear.

Comment: @BillyKerr  I don't think it's unclear. Freehand (F6) is Inkscapes free line drawing tool. He wants to connect the symbols with lines, i'd assume for an electric wiring scheme. He's fighting with the snapping settings and also wants to draw arcs at line crossings to show they don't touch. Typical technical drawing stuff.

Comment: @BillyKerr Freehand is a [tool](https://inkscape.org/it/doc/tutorials/advanced/tutorial-advanced.en.html) of Inkscape, and for Inkscape grid you can also see [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/63403/snap-to-grid-in-inkscape). The question is  related to how to give evidence of the intersection of the lines in a diagram, e.g. with a half circle.

Comment: @Diegov I don't think that Inkscape is able to manage automatically the intersection of two lines. There are manual ways like the [knot effect](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-LivePathEffects-Knot.html) or the [connectors](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Connectors-Modifying.html) - you can also double click the selected path on the intersection in order to create a node and add something. This specific feature (present in other tools like [yEd](https://www.yworks.com/products/yed)) is missing because Inkscape keeps strictly compliant to SVG specifications imho.

Comment: @AAGD - I was thinking of Macromedia Freehand rather than the Draw Freehand tool - yes some people still Macromedia Freehand!

Comment: to the OP, have you tried switching off the "Snap to Grid", and instead enable both "Snap Nodes or Handles" and "Snap to Cusp Nodes"?

Comment: [This](https://imgur.com/a/Clajx) is what I'm trying to draw. Thanks a lot for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the pen tool instead (Shift + F6). Assuming your drawings are vectors so you can snap to them, I would make a connector template like shown below. Line up the ends to make connections and with the direct selection tool (F2) select the nodes that make up the semi-circle and move them up/down left/right wherever to make a diagram.
[image: Connection Template]